# $.post vs $.ajax throws invalid json primitive 'data'

Tags: jquery

**WORKS NOT**

```
$.post('Schoolyear/Create', { data: JSON.stringify({ schoolyearId: 1 }) });
```

throws exception internal server error 500: invalid json primitive 'data'

**WORKS**

```
$.ajax('Schoolyear/Create', { data: JSON.stringify({ schoolyearId: 1 }), type: 'POST' });
```

Why can I not use the explicit $.post and have to write the type instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$.post( "Schoolyear/Create", { "schoolyearId": 1 } );
```

You don't need the JSON.stringify as its already a json string. 
And you don't need the data part either. See [jquery $.post page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more examples.

Comment: ah I just read only the jquery ajax documenation, thanks. About json. Why is { schoolyearId: 1 } a json string for you? its a javascript object literal would it be a json string it would have quotes around the schoolyearId key. I have just tried your code and as I have thought it does not work. It only works with JSON.stringify(...)  :-)

Comment: Why have you added quotes? If you want to make it json then the schoolyearId have to be in quotes but the number 1 not ;-)